# Inverse of a number module 2**255 -19

Tags: ring-theory, modules, inverse

I don't understand this code to solve the inverse of a number:

> `b = 256;`
>   `q = 2**255 - 19`
>
> `def expmod(b,e,m):
>     if e == 0: return 1
>     t = expmod(b,e/2,m)**2 % m
>     if e & 1: t = (t*b) % m
>     return t`
>
> `def inv(x):
>     return expmod(x,q-2,q)`

Finally, If I want to put: $\frac{2}{3}$ I can to do this: `aux=2*inv(3)`

What does the variable `e` mean?

Could you explain me this code, please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: $expmod(b,e,m)$ actually returns $b^e \pmod m$. In the case where $q$ is a prime, $b^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod q$. So $b\cdot b^{q-2} \equiv 1 \pmod q$ and that gives you the inverse. Indeed this algorithm is quite inefficient...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: Thanks. I understood what you say to me. But the code when e=0 return 1, ok. But else, why the code put $e/2$ @HwChu

Comment: $e$ is the exponent and any number to the power $0$ (except $0$) is $1$.  This code defines $0^0=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the number $p:=2^{255}-19$ is prime. Then $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ for all $x\not\equiv 0\pmod p$ (Little Fermat).
Hence we find $x^{-1}\bmod p$ by computing $x^{p-2}$.
The function $\operatorname{expmod}(x,y,m)$ computes $x^y\bmod m$ by using these observations:

- $x^0\equiv 1\pmod m$
- $x^{2k}\equiv x^k\cdot x^k\pmod m$
- $x^{2k+1}\equiv x^{2k}\cdot x\pmod m$.